# I don't understand my git tree. Can anybody explain to me and tell me how to fix?

Tags: git, version-control

I'm very beginner when it comes to GIT or Version Control System. I use only the Git Basics: edit -> add -> commit -> push

I'm working on my repository [Github's SFTPSpider](https://github.com/rasouza/SFTPSpider/network) and I can't understand what does mean this blue line and why it's so messed up. Everything should be linear, at least I worked on that way. Can somebody explain me what it is and why it is that way?

I know that I have a new branch called open-feature, but this should be branched from black line (not blue one)

Would be nice if you could provide me a solution to clean this up. I wish it was only the black line and the open-feature branch's line. Also, advise me how to avoid this mess again in the future, 'cause I don't know what I did to make it happen

My network graph: [image]

I think that it happened mostly because I edited and commited before `git pull`. When that happens, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

What I see when I follow your link looks like:
[image]

So possibly you have some private commits or some such or perhaps you just need to look into your settings.

Comment: That's because I made it all again. Every time I tried `rebase`, my tree would become worse

Comment: So it would be nice to change your question to say "this is the state you got into, this is how you got out!  How do you avoid it happening in the future?"

Answer (score -1):

```
git checkout open-features
git rebase master
```